# Explain better the steps of officebackgroundtaskhandler.exe fast appear and dissapear issue?

Tags: terminal, office365

I do have the steps, my Windows is in french but I can deduce what to click. It's just that I need more exact steps to guess better the translation and the idea:

1. Open Search Windows
2. What program to type ?
3. What to click in the program to see and change users ?

> There are two scheduled tasks un Task Scheduler
>   Quoted from Costas2 in April 2017,
>   Library/Microsoft/Office:
>
> OfficeBackgroundTaskHandlerLogon that runs when a user logs on and
>   OfficeBackgroundTaskHandlerRegistration that runs every hour
>
> Both were set to run under the "Users" account group. Since I didn't
>   notice any popup at logon, I set
>   OfficeBackgroundTaskHandlerRegistration to run under the "System"
>   account and the hourly popups are now hidden. (Select the task, right
>   click, Properties, click on 'Change User Or Group', type 'System', OK
>   twice and voila.)
>
> This is not the best solution from a security point of view, but until
>   MS fixes it, it works for me.

It's mostly for me to understand how to fix the Windows bugs without saying nonesense all the time, and in case there are other terminal windows types that opens all the time later. Windows said it already sent the fix to the bug: " The fix is now available in mainstream builds 16.8210.2075 released on 6/6/17 " So we don't need to do nothing, just wait. It's just that I was beginning to understand informatics and now I'm totally lost, I have no idea where to begin, neither how to follow the steps quoted.

Quote is from here:
[OfficeBackgroundTaskHandlerRegistration flashes a window every hour (Microsoft Answers, 2017)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_officeinsider-mso_win10/officebackgroundtaskhandlerregistration-flashes-a/2600497e-78e4-41a1-9040-461cd2c3ea13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Microsoft Office. Open any Office 2016 app and choose:

`File > Account > Update Options > Update`

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_officeinsider-mso_win10/officebackgroundtaskhandlerregistration-flashes-a/2600497e-78e4-41a1-9040-461cd2c3ea13)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer: `Fichier > Compte > Mises à jour pour Office` (fr)

Although I won't do it, I found that on the net today, seems like it answers my question, just a quote found:

> Kevin Angus  replied to Steel Horn
>
> ‎05-31-2017 06:24 AM Re: OfficeBackgroundTaskHandlerRegistration
>   comman...
>
> Open a DOS window enter Taskschd.msc OR open Control
>   Panel/Administrative Tools/Task Scheduler
>
> Click to the left of Task Scheduler Library on the >
>
> Click to the left of Microsoft on the >
>
> Click on the Office folder
>
> Click on the forth (4th) item down below Name in the center of the
>   window
>
> Verify it is OfficeBackgroundTaskHandlerRegistration
>
> Double Click the forth (4th) item to open the edit window
>
> In Security options
>
> Click on Change User or Group...
>
> In the Enter the object name to select box enter system and click
>   Check Names
>
> Click OK
>
> Click OK

Quote found here: [Microsoft's Techcommunity](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365-ProPlus/OfficeBackgroundTaskHandlerRegistration-command-prompt-window/td-p/72221)